# Will it affect SEO to use one header and footer file or copy the code in every page?

Tags: seo, html, template

I want to create a static website. All of my pages have same header and footer.
Should I have a single header/footer file and include it in my pages? OR should I reuse the code in all pages?

Will any of it affect SEO?
If I have to include the files, how to do it? I have seen some solutions with php and iframe. I don't want to use both.

Comment: Pretty much every site uses the same header and footer on all their pages.  There is no way that it would hurt SEO to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it similar to this:

```
<?php 
include("templates/header.php")
?>
```

the file will be "included" like its part of the original file. It should not make a difference to putting it in every document.
Using PHP it gets loaded on server-side = fast.

Some other ways to include things like headers in HTML : https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/